# How to respond to ありがとう?

Tags: politeness

I get it that ありがとう means "thanks", is informal without the ございます added to it and so on. 
However, I do not know what I should say after someone thanked me. In English, you generally say something like "No problem" or "You're welcome", it is similar in German as well. 
But what do you say in Japanese?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25839/1628

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`いえいえ` is an informal way to respond to `ありがとう`; similar to saying "No problem" or "Don't mention it."

`どういたしまして` means "You're welcome" and is more polite/formal.

Comment: いえいえ can be followed by 何でもない(よ) or 何でもないです or 何でもありません, which literally makes it, "No no, it's nothing."

Answer (score 3):

"Ie ie", literally "no no" is the same as "no problem" in this context.